# Query accross a circle of tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, database-design

I'm curious about how I could go about getting the data I need out of a "circle" of tables.

I have 5 tables(and a few supporting ones): 3 entities joined by junction tables.  So the general model is like this:

*Cards* have many *Budgets*, and *Accounts* have many *Budgets*, and *Accounts* have many *Cards*.

So my relationships make a circle, through the junction tables, form Card to Budget to Account back to Card, This structure works all fine and dandy until today when I tried to construct a query using all 5 tables, and noticed that I know of no way to avoid abiguous joins which this structure in place.  I'm thinking it might have been a better idea to create AccountBudget and CardBudget tables, but since they will both define exactly the same type of data, one table seemed more efficient.

The information I'm trying to get is basically the total budget limit for all cards of a certain type, and the total budget limit for all accounts of that same type.  Am I just looking at this problem wrong?

```
// Card             Budget_Card       Budget        Budget_Account         Account
// -------          ---------         --------      --------------         ---------
// cardId------\    budgetId<---------budgetId------>budgetId         -----accountId--(to Card)->
// accountId    --->cardId            limit          accountId<------/      typeId
// (etc)                              typeId                             (etc)

//  (typeId in Budget is either 1 for an account budget or 2 for a card budget.)
```

As you can see, it's a circle.  What I'm trying to accomplish is return one row with two columns:  the sum of `Budget.limit` for the record in `Account` where `typeId = 1`, and the sum of `Budget.limit` for all rows in `Card` belonging to `Account`s of the same type.

As per suggestion, I can in fact get the data I need from a union, but it's no use to me if the data is not in two separate columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Sum(Budget.limit) AS SumOfLimit
FROM (Account RIGHT JOIN Card ON Account.accountId = Card.accountId)
RIGHT JOIN (Budget LEFT JOIN Budget_Card ON Budget.budgetID = Budget_Card.budgetId) ON Card.cardId = Budget_Card.cardId
GROUP BY Budget.typeId, Budget.quarterId, Account.typeId
HAVING (((Budget.typeId)=2) AND ((Budget.quarterId)=[@quarterId]) AND ((Account.typeId)=[@accountType]))

UNION SELECT DISTINCTROW Sum(Budget.limit) AS SumOfLimit
FROM Budget LEFT JOIN (Account RIGHT JOIN Budget_Account ON Account.accountId = Budget_Account.accountId) ON Budget.budgetID = Budget_Account.budgetId
GROUP BY Budget.typeId, Budget.quarterId, Account.typeId
HAVING (((Budget.typeId)=1) AND ((Budget.quarterId)=[@quarterId]) AND ((Account.typeId)=[@accountType]));
```

Comment: show us the schema.. we can help better.

Comment: Added table structure and how I calculate total budget for Cards of a given Account type.

Comment: @wtfsven; Seems to me that this is not a query issue -- could you add definitions to your question.
1. What is Card? (include an example)
2. What is Budget? (example)
3. What is Account? (example)

Comment: I solved the problem by using the Budget table twice to avoid the joins creating a circle.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly, you've made separate column headers with the same name, and so your data becomes skewed because the information needs to be separated? If this is the case I would suggest changing the column headers as you've proposed, or in linking two queries together. To connect the data by querying the same tagged name will combine results. If you want to designate something, it's always a good idea to create separate names for column headers.

Here is an explanation of using SQL to query multiple tables: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-query-multiple-tables/1050307

Answer (score 0):

First make the query for the Cards, then union with the query for the Accounts

Although it would be easier to relate cards to accounts and then only have budgets for accounts, however i don't know if that would work with your schema